# Sending Table Data to Email with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, email

Am trying to send an email with the contents of a dynamic table to an email.
I have tried several methods but they have not worked for me thus far. If I try to put in the php code I get a blank page on load.

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 
        $to = "myemailg@hotmail.com";
        $subject = "Parking Log";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";           
        $message = "
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Car Log</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php //This prints out the car log data
        echo "<h3>Log of ".$_SESSION['date']." </h3>";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM carLog";
        $result = $databaseConnection->query($sql);
        echo "<table class='TFtable' border='1' style='width':100%>"; //starts the table tag
        echo "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Vehicle</td><td>Licence Plate</td><td>In</td><td>Out</td><td>Comments</td></tr>"; //sets headings
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //loops for each result
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['vehicle']."</td><td>".$row['plate']. "</td><td>".$row['inTime']."</td><td>".$row['outTime']."</td><td>".$row['comments']."</td>";
        }
        echo "</table>"; //closes the table
        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";
        $message = wordwrap($message, 70);    
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
```

I have the content display on the page with the same code that I have within the body tags and thats working fine. I just want all the content that I am displaying to be sent through email. But as it is the page wont even load.

Comment: full of syntax errors, look at the colour coding. start using and IDE that will point theses things out to you

Comment: ummm I am...If your talking about the code inside the body tags its a direct copy and paste from further down the page where it works perfectly to display the table so how can there be syntax errors there?

Comment: where does the `$message` string end? why do you have opening php tags in the middle of an already open php block ... the page will be screaming errors at you if you had error checking\display turned on:  turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: $message end right after the closing html tag, there is an opening php tag because im trying to display php within the email im sending, will turn on to see what i get.

Comment: no php does not work like that

Comment: so your saying its not possible for this to work? also whats up with the negative vote dude...

Comment: nothing can or will work until you fix the syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if it works but look for the minor changes

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 
            $to = "myemailg@hotmail.com";
            $subject = "Parking Log";
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";           
            $message = "
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Car Log</title>
            </head>
            <body>";
            $body = "<h3>Log of ".$_SESSION['date']." </h3>";

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM carLog";
            $result = $databaseConnection->query($sql);

            $body .= "<table class='TFtable' border='1' style='width':100%>"; //starts the table tag
            $body .= "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Vehicle</td><td>Licence Plate</td><td>In</td><td>Out</td><td>Comments</td></tr>"; //sets headings
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //loops for each result
            $body .= "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['vehicle']."</td><td>".$row['plate']. "</td><td>".$row['inTime']."</td><td>".$row['outTime']."</td><td>".$row['comments']."</td>";
            }
            $body .= "</table>"; //closes the table
            $message .= $body . "
            </body>
            </html>";
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70);    
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        }
```

Comment: this does indeed allow the page to render, lets see if it emails properly now. Thanks for actually helping :)

Comment: no luck on sending the email, changed the receiver to my email to test it and I have not gotten anything. I read that it does not work for local so i uploaded it and still no email. I read somewhere else that the mail() command is not supported by all hosts and that there is another php method to send emails. Any one know how to go about that?